# Solution to a kinetic temperature problem

Tags: thermodynamics, molecular-dynamics

I have a particular equation that needs to be solved for the kinetic temperature of a stream of gas particles. If we let the kinetic temperature be designated by the letter x, the equation becomes,

$$15 = \frac{x}{1+ x \, \ln {\left( 1+0.6\, e^{-15.7/x} \right)}/4}$$

where $\ln()$ is, obviously, the natural logarithm function. What techniques can be used to solve this and is there any particular technique that always arrives at some form of solution?

Comment: Welcome to physics.stackexchange. Please use TeX syntax when writing equations. You may need to provide more details for this problem.

Comment: Yes, please give more details: I do not believe that equation has a real (*i.e* in $\mathbb{R}$) solution.

Comment: Numerical methods seem to be the prime choice here.

Comment: According to WolframAlpha, there are no solutions.